# ('07002', "[07002] Parameters exist but IPD isn't set. Please call SQLDescribeParam() (32) (SQLExecDirectW)") But there are no parameters?

Tags: sql, python-3.7, pyodbc

Why am I getting this error when there is no parameter in the execute statement???

I am trying to create a table with pyodbc. Here is the code and the error:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
import os

file = 'C:\\Users\\xx\\Documents\\xx\\xxx\\a_file.csv'

def cursor_pyodbcdsn(encoding = True, get_cnxn=False):
    """Connection established via system DSN driver in ODBC."""
    connection = pyodbc.connect("DSN=PostgreSQL35W", autocommit=False)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    if get_cnxn: 
        return cursor, connection
    else:
        return cursor

cursor, cnxn = cursor_pyodbcdsn(get_cnxn=True)

df = pd.read_csv(file)
tb = os.path.basename(file).split('.')[0]

c = lambda df: ' TEXT NULL, '.join([i for i in df.columns]) + ' TEXT NULL'
q = lambda tb, df: f"CREATE TABLE {tb} ({c(df)})"

cursor.execute(q(table_name, df))
cursor.commit()
```

**Error:**

> ('07002', "[07002] Parameters exist but IPD isn't set. Please call
> SQLDescribeParam() (32) (SQLExecDirectW)")